# In Python, why doesn't dataclasses.asdict work with fields of type dictionary?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Why doesn't dataclasses.asdict work with dictionary values (not keys)?

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass, field


@dataclass(order=True, frozen=True, eq=True)
class Path:
    p: tuple[str, ...] = field(default=())


@dataclass
class C:
    p: dict[Path, int] = field(default_factory=dict)


path = Path(('x', 'y'))
print(hash(path), asdict(path))
c = C({path: 1})
print(asdict(c))  # TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataclasses.asdict` attempts to be a "deep" operation. It will recursively explore dataclass instances, tuples, lists, and dicts, and attempt to convert all dataclass instances it finds into dicts.

It even does this when those dataclass instances appear as dict keys, even though trying to use the resulting dict as a dict key will always throw a TypeError.

For your use case, and a lot of others, it makes more sense to just use `c.__dict__` instead of `dataclasses.asdict(c)`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm actually counting on the recursive behaviour.  I just expected it not to apply `asdict` to the keys of the `dict`.  I need an `asdict` that either produces `frozendict`-like instances or doesn't apply to the keys of dicts.